# Internal Server Error Azure Rest Api put request to create Database

Tags: asp.net, database, rest, api, azure

I have been receiving this error when making a put request to the Azure Rest Api:

```
    {"code":"InternalServerError",
"message":"There was an internal server error that occurred during this request.",
"target":null,
"details":[],
"innererror":[]}
```

The query I use is:(With the correct values substituting the {example} fields)

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}?api-version=2014-04-01
```

The Put request I am sending is with this content (the header contains aplication/json):

```
{"location":"southcentralus"}
```

I have tried different variation of South Central US to no avail. I have put in Japan East and it tells me invalid resource location (so i know my query is in the right place).

The documentation says location and databasename are the bare minimum so I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

PS I am using asp.net to send the rest requests but I believe the code behind that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There was an internal server error that occurred during this request.

According to your error information, it indicates there is something wrong with Azure SQL server.

Please have a try to **create it with Azure portal** to check whether it can be created correctly. If you also can't create the database from Azure portal, please conect to Azure Suppport.

Or please have a try to **create a new AzureSQL server** and try it again. I test the create Azure SQL Database API on my side with Postman it works correctly on my side.

Header:

[image]

Body:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. My error was newtonsoft.json settings were serializing my model with null values which created the internal server error.


Do you by chance know why the response body is `{"operation":"CreateLogicalDatabase","startTime":"\/Date(1495559091010+0000)\/"}`


The documentation for arm api says it should return a [full json definition of the database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases#Databases_CreateOrUpdate)


I assume the reason is because its processing the request but I would like to confirm the completion of creation. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `Is there a way to do that?` We can use the Rest API Get method to get the database status, `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}?api-version=2014-04-01` If the database status is online, then we could know that it is finished.